# How to change the brightness of an HSV image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, hsv, canny-operator

I want to change the brightness of an image. Here's the code I used.

```
rgbImage = imread('C:\Users\AHII\Desktop\IEEE\Original\01.jpg');
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);
hChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 1);
sChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 2);
vChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 3);
%newS = (5) * sChannel;     
%newS = sChannel / (0.5) ; 
%newS = (-0.5) * sChannel;
newHSVImage = cat(3, hChannel, newS, vChannel);
newRGBImage = hsv2rgb(newHSVImage);
```

There are three patterns in the code part I made as the command. I don't know which is the right way to use. I need to get ten different brightness level images. Is there a range level for newS? I am currently using 0.5 - 2.5 with step interval of 0.5 such as, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 and also minus values like -0.5, -1.0 and so on. I saw this code too while I was checking.

```
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);
hChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 1);
sChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 2);
vChannel = hsvImage(:, :, 3);
meanV = mean2(vChannel);
newV = meanV + 0.5 * (vChannel - meanV); 
newHSVImage = cat(3, hChannel, sChannel, newV);
newRGBImage = hsv2rgb(newHSVImage);
```

So Is it V Channel or S Channel for brightness and please comment on the factor value which is used and its range.

Comment: Multiplying V by a positive value changes the brightness. Multiplying by a value larger than one increases it, by a value lower than one decreases it. The second bit of code changes the contrast. It keeps the average brightness, and brings dark and light parts closer to the average.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo So Can I use any factor to increase and decrease

Comment: Any positive factor. You might get out of bounds values, though. When increasing brightness, for example by multiplying by 2, an input value `0.7` will become `1.4`. That is larger than 1, the upper limit. Setting `newV = min(newV,1)` clips any values above 1 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSV refers to Hue, Saturation, Value. Hue and Saturation channels carry information about color, while Value carries information about intensity (essentially brightness) . So Value (V) is the channel that should be changed if you want to change the image brightness.

Value (V) will be in the interval [0,1] where 0 is minimum intensity and 1 is maximum . So you will want values for different brightness to be in that interval.

If you adjust an existing V, you must take steps to ensure that the output V remains in the [0,1] interval. As suggested in the comment by @Cris Luengo one way to do that would be

```
newV = factor*vChannel; % where factor is a positive number
newV = min(newV,1);
newHSVImage = cat(3, hChannel, sChannel, newV);
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks much @paisanco . Value V is in the interval [0,1]. Is it okay to multiply this value by a factor of let's say 0.2 and 2 or should I find the V value of my image and ensure a factor that will give a product between the range [0 - 1]. Let's say V of my image is 0.5. This means, The factor I can multiply can be a anything or between, [0, 2]